# passing array of ints into mssql sp from laravel for using in the "in" operator

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

i have a mssql sp which one of it's arguments is table-valued. i want to pass an array of int's to it from laravel project.
i tried this :

```
DB::connection("sqlsrv")->select(
            "Exec spName @table-valuedParam=?, param2=?.., array(arrayofInt, param2..) )
```

and i get the error : 
parameter mismatch, pattern need string but array given.

my purpose is  to select records from table which id's in the the that array, actually the sp contain a section like this 
where id in (@idList)
i using table-valued but can pass an array from laravel to it. how can do this?

is there any way to do this job?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: You could go through the array with a for loop and pass each array element separately. That way, you check all values in the array and don't have the trouble of trying to pass the whole array at once.

Comment: @Geshode there is a lot of data and i want to sql server filter data. this way is not cost effective. thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching a lot i get an answer. 
i pass user selected id's as a string with comma seperated and create a sql server function which do the split job and return a table of int's and then i use where clause like :
select * from mytable where id in (select * from sqlsrvFunc(@idsStr)
it's worked porfectly